# How to evolve an ASP.NET Core Minimal APIs to a full controller model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, minimal-apis

My teacher told today that Minimal API allow start with minimal code and evolve the application with time in a way you end having a Controller folder and automatic routing as an traditional ASP.NET Coree MVC app/API.

I loved the idea of fast starting development with a simple file mapping all routes in so simple way but would like a way to convert it to a full routing when it becomes cluttered or when development becomes more serious or client/teacher ask for it without coding everything from scratch again.

Initially I just want a simple way to have Postgres Migrations, my connection string in `appsettings.json`, Swagger, JWT+SocialLogin and would be great have my models on a separate project too.

I was searching about and just found a Microsoft [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#request-handling), but nothing about turning  routing in the traditional way.

It pops-up here too: [Controllers and Endpoints in Net 6 Minimal API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235837/controllers-and-endpoints-in-net-6-minimal-api)

Answer (score 2):

**Hi** , When you use Minimal Api in .Net 6 , There is no `builder.Services.AddControllers()` and
`app.MapControllers()` in `Program,cs` .

But , If you want to evolve an ASP.NET Core Minimal APIs to a full controller model , You need to add `builder.Services.AddControllers()` and
`app.MapControllers()` in `Program.cs` by yourself

**Attention:** there is some Differences between `minimal APIs` and `APIs with controllers` , you can read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#differences-between-minimal-apis-and-apis-with-controllers) to learn more details