# I need to put all app.MapGet/Post/Put/Delete requests into controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I got minimal API working with MongoDB and I need to put all request methods into a "PersonController" controller

```
app.MapGet("/api/users", () =>
    db.GetCollection<Person>(collectionName).Find("{}").ToListAsync());
 
app.MapGet("/api/users/{id}", async (string id) =>
{
    var user = await db.GetCollection<Person>(collectionName)
        .Find(p=>p.Id == id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 
    if (user == null) return Results.NotFound(new { message = "User is not found" });
 
    return Results.Json(user);
});
app.MapDelete("/api/users/{id}", async (string id) =>
{
    var user = await db.GetCollection<Person>(collectionName).FindOneAndDeleteAsync(p=>p.Id==id);
    // if not found send status code and error message
    if (user is null) return Results.NotFound(new { message = "User is not found" });
    return Results.Json(user);
});

app.MapPost("/api/users", async (Person user) => {
 
    // adding user to the list
    await db.GetCollection<Person>(collectionName).InsertOneAsync(user);
    return user;
});
 
app.MapPut("/api/users", async (Person userData) => {
 
    var user = await db.GetCollection<Person>(collectionName)
        .FindOneAndReplaceAsync(p => p.Id == userData.Id, userData, new() { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After });
    if (user == null) 
        return Results.NotFound(new { message = "User is not found" });
    return Results.Json(user);
});
```

I'm new to .NET and I don't know how to put these requests into controller.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661175/how-to-evolve-an-asp-net-core-minimal-apis-to-a-full-controller-model) might be useful

Comment: Could you please share, which version of .NET you are using? In addition, you can create a new controller along with your DbContext constructor and then you can dbContext instance then just place all of your minimal controller action there, you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got minimal API working with MongoDB and I need to put all request
> methods into a "PersonController" controller. I'm new to .NET and I
> don't know how to put these requests into controller.

Actually, creating API controller in .NET application is pretty straightforward and simple regardless of its version. I am not sure, which version of .NET you are using, but I am sharing you, how you can achieve your reqirement in .NET 7.

Following two way, you can include your existing minimum API actions, either creating new API project or creating new API controller within the existing project.

Create new API controller in existing project:

1. Create new folder name with Controllers:

[image]

You should have following folder and name:

[image]

2. Create new web API controller name with person and Replace your code in following way:

[image]

[image]

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly PersonService _personService;

        public PersonController(PersonService personService) =>
            _personService = personService;

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Person>> Get() =>
            await _personService.Find();

        [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> Get(string id)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return person;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Person newPerson)
        {
            await _personService.InsertOneAsync(newPerson);

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = newPerson.Id }, newPerson);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, Person updatedPerson)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            updatedPerson.Id = person.Id;

            await _personService.ReplaceOneAsync(id, updatedPerson);

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var person = await _personService.Find(id);

            if (person is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _personService.DeleteOneAsync(id);

            return NoContent();
        }


    }
```

Demo Model:

```
public class Person
    {
       public string Id { get; set; }   
       public string Name { get; set; }   
    }
```

Mongo Collection Configuration:

```
public class PersonDatabaseSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;

        public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;

        public string GetCollection { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Db Collection Service:

```
public class PersonService
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<Person> _personCollection;

        public PersonService(
            IOptions<PersonDatabaseSettings> personDatabaseSettings)
        {
            var mongoClient = new MongoClient(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

            var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

            _personCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Person>(
                personDatabaseSettings.Value.GetCollection);
        }

        public async Task<List<Person>> Find() =>
            await _personCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Person?> Find(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        public async Task InsertOneAsync(Person newPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.InsertOneAsync(newPerson);

        public async Task ReplaceOneAsync(string id, Person updatedPerson) =>
            await _personCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == id, updatedPerson);

        public async Task DeleteOneAsync(string id) =>
            await _personCollection.DeleteOneAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

**Note:** I am using additional service class, but you can continue, your approach as well.

Program.cs:

As you have taken minimum api, so while you would be taking API controller, youu should update your program.cs file as following:

```
using APIProject.Controllers;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.Configure<PersonDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PersonDatabase"));

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

**Note:** Wen should registered mongo Db client and PersonService DI in program.cs same as above.

Output:

> I haven't installed mongo db instance in my VM, so collection would
> throw an null reference exception, but it would work if there is an
> data collection.

[image]

**Note:** For any implementation challenge or further information [please refer to this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-controller)

Comment: Thank you so much, this doesn't crash my app, yet I still have problem, CRUD operations aren't performed, so I guess I need to connect this app to my existing mongodb database "test" with collection "users". Like I said I'm new to .Net, so how do I do that?

Comment: Well, I got your point, you can create the users service and call your mongo collection within it and finally, call the within yyour controller. If you encounter any further issue, post new question with that description, this answer has solely written for how you can rewrite minimum api in web API controller.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample PersonController in .net core. in your API projects.
click add new controller. name it person.
put your stuffs there

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Repositories;
using AutoMapper;
using Entity;

namespace API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult List()
        {
            // ur code
            return Ok();
        }

        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Put(int id)
        {
             // ur code
              
             return Ok();
        }

        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
             // ur code
             return Ok();
        }

        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(int id)
        {
             // ur code
             return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

sample programme class

```
using Entity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Repositories;;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<DBContext>(Options =>
{
    Options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HrSoultion"));
    Options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll);
});
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: "{controller=TestController}/{action=list}/{id?}");
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.Run();
```

if you need clear speration of concerns. i suggest you read more about repository design pattern and unitofwork in entity framwork.

or you can use ADO.NET To connect to sql server datatabse.